# Sync 2 list boxes to 1 scrollbar

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, scroll, listbox, listbox-control

I have 2 listboxes next to each other. One holds the order the other holds the total cost of the order.

For obvious reasons i need both listboxes to scroll simultaneously.

Here is what i have tried

```
Private Sub lstOrders_Scroll()
    lstTotalsEachOrder.TopIndex = lstOrders.TopIndex
End Sub

Private Sub lstTotalsEachOrder_Scroll()
    lstOrders.TopIndex = lstTotalsEachOrder.TopIndex
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated.

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and I'm coding in vb.

From what I read _Scroll has been removed.

I was thinking that I could remove the scrollbar on the order listbox and control the both boxes by the scroller on the totals listbox.

Comment: You could be using a `DataGridView` and display the data in columns - then there is no need for this kind of workaround.

Comment: If the items in each ListBox are related to each other, you might be better off putting all the information in a ListView or DataGridView. That way they will scroll together and you don't have to worry about syncing them.

Comment: @OneFineDay Im not allowed to used tables, thanks for the response, any other options?

Comment: @Blackwood I'm not allowed to use a database, so i dont thnink i can use DataGridView, ill look into Listview now.

Comment: @Blackwood could you to a quick run through on how to set up a list view, adding and removing items, and selecting the last value added

Comment: @OneFineDay Well, im managing 4 listbox over 2 forms, 1 form is for the order and the other is a summery form where they can save the listboxes to a file.

Comment: @IeuanWalker: I think what OneFineDay wants to know is are you asking us to help you with your homework.

Comment: @blackwood oh then ye

Comment: @IeuanWalker: The [MSDN documentation for the ListView Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) includes an example of how to use it.

Comment: I hope my answer isn't too late

Comment: @BrandonB it wasn't thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep the selected indexes in sync, then you could do this:

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub ListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim parentListBox As ListBox = DirectCast(sender, ListBox)
        Dim childListBox As ListBox = DirectCast(parentListBox.Tag, ListBox)

        If parentListBox.SelectedIndex < childListBox.Items.Count Then
            childListBox.SelectedIndex = parentListBox.SelectedIndex
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Me.ListBox1.Tag = Me.ListBox2
        Me.ListBox2.Tag = Me.ListBox1
        AddHandler ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf ListBox_SelectedIndexChanged
        AddHandler ListBox2.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf ListBox_SelectedIndexChanged
    End Sub

End Class
```

However to get the actual scrolling to sync up, you'd need to draw the listbox items yourself. The following accomplishes this task, but it's really slow to scroll the parent `listbox`.

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Me.ListBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed
        Me.ListBox2.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed
        Me.ListBox1.Tag = Me.ListBox2
        Me.ListBox2.Tag = Me.ListBox1
        AddHandler Me.ListBox1.DrawItem, AddressOf ListBox_DrawItem
        AddHandler Me.ListBox2.DrawItem, AddressOf ListBox_DrawItem
    End Sub

    Private Sub ListBox_DrawItem(sender As Object, e As DrawItemEventArgs)
        Dim parentListBox As ListBox = DirectCast(sender, ListBox)
        Dim childListBox As ListBox = DirectCast(parentListBox.Tag, ListBox)
        e.DrawBackground()
        e.DrawFocusRectangle()

        Dim brsh As New SolidBrush(Color.Black)

        If String.Compare(e.State.ToString, DrawItemState.Selected.ToString) > 0 Then brsh.Color = Color.White

        e.Graphics.DrawString(CStr(parentListBox.Items(e.Index)), e.Font, brsh, New RectangleF(e.Bounds.Location, e.Bounds.Size))

        childListBox.TopIndex = parentListBox.TopIndex

    End Sub

End Class
```

Also take note that there is no error checking to make sure that the items can actually be scrolled to, so if one `listbox` has more items, you'll get an exception at runtime.

Comment: Thank you sooo much, this works brilliantly :D. Originally i was using this lstOrders.TopIndex = lstOrders.Items.Count - 1
        lstTotalsEachOrder.TopIndex = lstTotalsEachOrder.Items.Count - 1,  to keep the latest order showing. But thanks i'll use these simultaneously

Comment: I used your second option btw :)

Comment: you wouldn't know how to hide a scrollbar on one listbox?

Comment: @IeuanWalker - Try `ListBox.ScrollAlwaysVisible = False`, but I fear you may not get the results you are expecting.

Comment: nope, i've tried that :/, i want one to be constantly hidden. I searched quite a few sites now, and i dont think its possible.

Comment: I'm posting on my phone and don't have my Dev machine handy. If that doesn't work then I'm pretty sure  the only way to remove the scroll bar is to override the `OnPaint` method and draw the entire control yourself.

Comment: Ahh thanks ill look into the onPaint method but i'm afraid i'm not advanced enough to write a draw method myself.

Comment: @IeuanWalker - Not hard, just a ton of work. Usually things like this are generally not needed. You are getting hung up in the wrong process of design. 1st: make everything just work at the basic level. 2nd: make the workflow efficient. 3rd: make it look pretty. Make sure steps 1 and 2 are done before you do anything in step 3. If you don't you'll find that you wasted time on a lot of things.

Comment: lol, everything works completely fine, and i just finished the design, i just personally dont like look / or think there's a need for the 2 scrollbars :)