# How to sync scroll positions of 3 listboxes in vb.net?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, listbox

I try to sync the following 3 listboxes using an timer event.

**Left:** Id

**Middle:** Listbox1

**Right:** Listbox2

```
Private GI_Sync_X_centerLine As Integer

GI_Sync_X_centerLine = (ListBox1.Left + ListBox1.Width + ListBox1.Left) \ 2 (here should be the issue)

Private Sub sync_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles sync.Tick
        If (ListBox1.TopIndex <> ListBox2.TopIndex) Then            ' out-of-sync
            If (ListBox1.Items.Count = ListBox2.Items.Count) Then   ' both are scrollable
                If ((MousePosition.X - Me.Location.X) < GI_Sync_X_centerLine) Then ' mouse is on the left one
                    ListBox2.TopIndex = ListBox1.TopIndex       ' move the right one to match
                Else
                    ListBox1.TopIndex = ListBox2.TopIndex       ' & v.v.
                End If
            End If
        End If

        If (id.TopIndex <> ListBox2.TopIndex) Then            ' out-of-sync
            If (id.Items.Count = ListBox2.Items.Count) Then   ' both are scrollable
                If ((MousePosition.X - Me.Location.X) < GI_Sync_X_centerLine) Then ' mouse is on the left one
                    ListBox2.TopIndex = id.TopIndex       ' move the right one to match
                Else
                    id.TopIndex = ListBox2.TopIndex       ' & v.v.
                End If
            End If
        End If

        If (id.TopIndex <> ListBox1.TopIndex) Then            ' out-of-sync
            If (id.Items.Count = ListBox1.Items.Count) Then   ' both are scrollable
                If ((MousePosition.X - Me.Location.X) < GI_Sync_X_centerLine) Then ' mouse is on the left one
                    ListBox1.TopIndex = id.TopIndex       ' move the right one to match
                Else
                    id.TopIndex = ListBox1.TopIndex       ' & v.v.
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Solution found at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/38413d0a-7388-4191-a7a6-fd66e469d502/two-listbox-scrollbar-in-synchronisation?forum=wpf and modified it for 3 listboxes.

***The problem is the following:***

**If I scroll the left listbox all others scroll too.
If I scroll the right listbox all others scroll too,
BUT if I try to scroll the middle listbox, the others do not scroll and the middle stucks at the position where the others are.**

Comment: i think issiue is in your IF/ELSE in first is `ListBox1` related to `ListBox2` so second IF/ELSE should be `id` to `ListBox1` and last one `ListBox2` to `id` or i miss something?

Comment: Tried it directly, same issue. But thx for the try :)

Comment: May the issue is in the `GI_Sync_X_centerLine`?

Comment: if we can chat somewhere it can be usefull (btw give me few minutes and i will try something)

Comment: if i provide solution for u in c# can u rewrite it to VB?

Comment: No I can't :/ Chatting actually isn't possible for me.

Comment: ok never mind i will try convert it

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function GetDescendantByType(element As Visual, type As Type) As Visual
    If element Is Nothing Then
        Return Nothing
    End If
    If element.[GetType]() = type Then
        Return element
    End If
    Dim foundElement As Visual = Nothing
    If TypeOf element Is FrameworkElement Then
        TryCast(element, FrameworkElement).ApplyTemplate()
    End If
    For i As Integer = 0 To VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element) - 1
        Dim visual As Visual = TryCast(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i), Visual)
        foundElement = GetDescendantByType(visual, type)
        If foundElement IsNot Nothing Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Return foundElement
End Function
Private Sub lb_ScrollChanged(sender As Object, e As ScrollChangedEventArgs)
    Dim _listboxScrollViewer1 As ScrollViewer = TryCast(GetDescendantByType(id, GetType(ScrollViewer)), ScrollViewer)
    Dim _listboxScrollViewer2 As ScrollViewer = TryCast(GetDescendantByType(listBox1, GetType(ScrollViewer)), ScrollViewer)
    Dim _listboxScrollViewer3 As ScrollViewer = TryCast(GetDescendantByType(listBox2, GetType(ScrollViewer)), ScrollViewer)
    _listboxScrollViewer2.ScrollToVerticalOffset(_listboxScrollViewer1.VerticalOffset)
    _listboxScrollViewer3.ScrollToVerticalOffset(_listboxScrollViewer2.VerticalOffset)
    _listboxScrollViewer1.ScrollToVerticalOffset(_listboxScrollViewer3.VerticalOffset)
End Sub
```

and associate lb_ScrollChanged as event `ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="lb_ScrollChanged"` to every ListBox

If u have some problems with that code, please reply.

Comment: How to associate that as event? Never worked with events before :)

Comment: Also `Visual` + `ScrollViewer` + `FrameworkElement` are not defined, `VisualTreeHelper is not declared`. Do I need something to import before?

Comment: u need 
`using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;`

Comment: just wrire ` ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="lb_ScrollChanged"` to your xaml, for example `<ListBox x:Name="listBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="213,43,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="lb_ScrollChanged"/>`

Comment: @realKSMC or this link should help u [From stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30484913/sync-2-list-boxes-to-1-scrollbar)